# How to display the name from the array name?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to study c++ about array
and I'm having a problem displaying the name from the array name

Because when I try to display the name of the passenger based on where he seat
the first letter becomes the last letter of his name..ahmm

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

char* name[10]={" "};
int* seat=0;
char* pname="The Passenger is: ";
char ask;
void display();

int main()
{
    clrscr();
    cout<<"The Entering of name and seat number..."<<endl;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter your name: ";
        cin>>*name;
        cout<<"Enter your seat number: ";
        cin>>*seat;
        cout<<"Do you want to input again?(Y/N): ";
        cin>>ask;
    }
    while(ask=='y'||ask=='Y');
    cout<<"\nDo you want to see the passenger's name?(Y/N): ";
    cin>>ask;
    if(ask=='y'||ask=='Y')
    {
        cout<<"\nThe Program will now direct you to the displaying of passenger's name...."<<endl;
        display();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nThe Program will end shortly....";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nEnter seat number to display passenger's name: ";
        cin>>*seat;
        cout<<pname<<*name[*seat-1]<<endl;
        cout<<"Do you want to try again?(Y/N): ";
        cin>>ask;
    }
    while(ask=='y'||ask=='Y');
    cout<<"\nThe Program will now end shortly....";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: `cin>>*name;` - You're trying to overwrite a string literal.

Comment: AFAIK `iostream.h` is not standardized. I think you should use `iostream`

Comment: `*name[*seat-1]` This might not do what you think it does!

Comment: One of the issues is that `seat` is just a pointer, and (as far as I can see) it never points to an actual integer. Trying to dereference it will therefore result in undefined behaviour (i.e. unpredictable, and potentially very bad). Try declaring it as an `int` (instead of an `int*`), and don't dereference it.

Comment: Should not it crash here `cin>>*seat;` because we have `int* seat=0;` ?

Comment: Actually, this should refuse to compile.  `char* name[10]={" "};` requires loss of const-qualification, which cannot be done implicitly.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Yet it unfortunately "should" before C++11 :(

Comment: @chris: C++03 does allow that to compile, true, but not without intense complaining from the compiler.  However the `c++` tag now means C++11.  And someone trying to learn C++ would be well advised to get a modern, C++11-compliant compiler and also turn up the warning level.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I agree completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***To display the name from the array name*** you have at first to define the array correctly.:)

If you do not know yet about standard class `std::string` then the array should be defined as for example

```
char name[10][20];
```

that is it can store 10 names that have length no more than 20 characters.

Or if you know about class `std:string` then you can define it as

```
#include <string>
std::string name[10];
```

And it would be even better to define

```
#include <string>
#include <array>
std::array<std::string, 10> name;
```

For this program neither pointer is needed to be defined.

Take into account that when you ask to enter a seat  number you should check that this number is in the range 1 - 10 (in this case you will need to decrease it by one when will use it to access the array) or 0 - 9.

Comment: It should be declared that way whether the OP knows about it already or not!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having a problem with pointers. Namely

```
int* seat=0;
```

will not allocate space for the integer, but instead allocate space for a pointer and then set this pointer and set it to address 0. When you perform

```
cin>>*seat;
```

Your program attempts to dereference the pointer which does not point to anything. Furthermore when you perform

```
cin >>*name
```

You are not writing to the whole string but instead writing to the dereference location, namely the first character of the string.

For a start change

```
int* seat=0;
```

to

```
int seat = 0
```

and

```
    cin>>*name;
```

to

```
    cin>>name;
```

good luck!

Edit:

also you want to change the:

```
    cin >> *seat;
```

to

```
    cin >> seat
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevertheless you might need some more practice in the basic language features, like pointers, you could use some existing data structures. Since you are using *cout* and *cin* i assume your compiler supports the C++ standard library. I would use a map, to save the passengers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct passenger
{
    char name[10];
};

std::map<int, passenger> passengers;
int seat;
char ask;

void display();

int main()
{
    std::cout<< "The Entering of name and seat number..." << std::endl;

    do
    {
        passenger p;
        std::cout << "\nEnter your name: ";
        std::cin >> p.name;
        std::cout << "Enter your seat number: ";
        std::cin >> seat;

        // add passenger to the map
    passengers.insert(std::pair<int, passenger>(seat, p));

        std::cout << "Do you want to input again?(Y/N): ";
        std::cin >> ask;
    }
    while(ask=='y'||ask=='Y');

    std::cout << "\nDo you want to see the passenger's name?(Y/N): ";

    std::cin >> ask;

    if(ask=='y' || ask=='Y')
    {
        std::cout << "\nThe Program will now direct you to the displaying of passenger's name...." << std::endl;
        display();
    }

    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    do
    {
        std::cout << "\nEnter seat number to display passenger's name: ";
        std::cin >> seat;

        // check if passenger data is available for this seat
        if(passengers.find(seat) != passengers.end()) {
            std::cout << "The Passenger is: " << passengers[seat].name << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Seat still available ..." << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Do you want to try again?(Y/N): ";
        std::cin >> ask;
    }
    while(ask=='y' || ask=='Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a pointer `*seat` you don't have to access it as
`cin>>*seat`. You only need to write `cin>>seat`.
While you are learning cpp, check out what pointers are too.

Here's a little info on that too, though that is not exactly the subject matter,

```
int *S;   // pointer of type int

int x;     // variable of type int

S = &x;    // pointer S is now pointing to memory location of x

S = 4;
```

OR

> x = 4;    // changes the contents of memory location to which S points`
>
> cout << *S;     // displays the memory address to which S points i.e.
> x